# GWT How can I access HTML5 variable

Tags: gwt, range, uibinder

I do have a line in ui.xml for horizontalsliderbar (HTML5).

Test.ui.xml

```
<input ui:field="slider1" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="30"
            step="10""></input>
```

Test.java

```
@UiField
InputElement slider1;
```

How can I get/set to value, min, max and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution could be:

```
slider1.setAttribute("min", "0");
slider1.setAttribute("max", "100");
slider1.setAttribute("value", "30");
slider1.setAttribute("step", "10");
```

Hope that helps.